# 1.12 Checkpoint System

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Note: This is not for 1.13, but 1.12

I want to create a checkpoint system for my Parkour map, but I fail everytime.
When a player stands on an emerald block, this should be his checkpoint. If he needs to get back, he should use an item (like Carrot on a Stick) to get back to his latest checkpoint. There will be more than 1 emerald block and this should be multiplayer friendly (for up to 4 players).

What I did:

1. Set up a scoreboard that checks if a carrot on a stick gets
   rightclicked, and on what team the player is (only 1 player per
   team)
2. An execute command that checks if the player stands on an command block. If it's true, an already summoned armor stand with the name will teleport to the player, while the command block is active.

When the player now fails, he can right click his carrot on a stick, to get teleported to the Armor stand (I don't have this command, because when the other thing don't works, it's useless anyways)

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoGravity:1b,Small:1b,Marker:1b,CustomName:"P1CP",DisabledSlots:2039583}
/execute @p[score_P1=1,score_P1_min=1] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:emerald_block 0 tp @e[Name:P1CP] @p
```

P1CP = Name of Armorstand (P1 = player 1; CP = checkpoint)

Comment: Hello ThaumicTom! Welcome to Stack Exchange! Could you please elaborate on the steps you are following to create the check point system?

Comment: Okay, i will try.

Comment: Tip: PersistanceRequired is not required for armor stands. It's there to prevent hostile mobs from despawning.

Comment: The second command teleports the armor stand that you created in the first command to any player standing on an emerald block, or to be exact, to the player standing on an emerald block that is closest to the command block. Is that what you intended? This doesn't teleport the player at all, so are you searching for that part of the command system that effectively respawns the player? In that case: Is the armor stand intended as a static checkpoint marker? Or did you already expect it to work, but you didn't notice that the armor stand was teleported to the player, because you didn't see it?

Comment: There is a syntax error in the last bit of the second command. you've written `@e[Name:P1CP]`, but it has to be `@e[Name=P1CP]`. It's probably not fixing your problem, but it fixes the command at least.

Comment: @Fabian Thanks for some heads up. I wanted that the armor stand gets teleported to the player, that stands on the emerald block, that has the score P1 (Player 1) identical to the armor stand name P1CP (Player 1 Checkpoint). The Armor Stand gets teleported, so the player can right click a carrot on a stick to get back to the armor stand.

Comment: @D-Inventor Thanks, I didn't saw that, I think this could potentially fix my problem. I will let you know in some moments.

Comment: I found the problem. Name needs to be written small like this:<pre>@e[name=P1CP]</pre> not <pre>@e[Name=P1CP]</pre>

Comment: Code blocks are made with \` at the beginning and end. About your comment from 16:58: Wouldn't you need one armor stand per player then? How are they linked to the player, meaning how do you know that e.g. P1CP is the checkpoint armor stand for player Horst and R2D2 is the checkpoint armor stand for player Karl? Or is it global, meaning that when any player arrives at a checkpoint, it's set for everybody? In that case, how would you avoid that one player activates checkpoint 1 by standing on it after another player activated checkpoint 2? Then they would both get teleported to 1 again later.

Comment: Read the answer in the question and try to replicate it, it should work. Thanks for the Head up with the backticks. If P1 (Player 1) stands on the emerald block P1CP gets teleported to them. P2 would have their own armor stand P2CP, which will only react when P2 stands on the emerald block NOT P1. Just make new command blocks for P2. What you really need is a "Team selector" which will only allow 1 player per team.

Comment: @ThaumicTom The rules are clear that [platform tags like "pc" should only be used when the question is asking specifically about the platform](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4639/185203) and that [questions should not include tags like "Minecraft 1.12: in their titles"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/566903). Your rejection of my suggested edit is not in accordance with those rules.

Comment: To add to what @pppery said, the title of the game and version (1.12) you are asking about are already in the question's tag and body. There is no need to replicate this information in the title.

Comment: This topic is over a Year old, it was designed for the Version 1.12 and it doesn't matter for a sudden change.

Comment: A question being old does not mean any ignored rule violations should continue to be ignored. The version is already in the first sentence of the body. I don't understand what "it doesn't matter for a sudden change" means. I'm not going to edit war just to remove the version from the title now that you have accepted the rest of my edit, but I still feel it is unnecessary.

Comment: This is literally necromancing. Is it really what people do? Edit posts from 2008 that only get viewed once a month at most? I will just consider deleting this post thanks to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

1. Create an scoreboard named "carrot" `/scoreboard objectives add carrot stat.useItem.minecraft.carrot_on_a_stick`
2. For multiplayer compatibility add a scoreboard named "P1" (for Player 1; needs Team selection) `/scoreboard objectives add P1 dummy`
3. In a command block put this command to summon the armor stand that is required to use this system `/summon armor_stand 151 102 -188 {Invisibility:1b,Invulnerable:1b,Small:1b,Marker:1b,CustomName:"P1CP",DisabledSlots:2039583}`
4. In a clock-command block place this command to test for the P1 player, that right clicked the carrot-rod `/testfor @p[score_P1=1,score_P1_min=1,score_carrot=1,score_carrot_min=1]`
5. Place three chain command blocks on conditional mode right behind the violet one (repeatable command block;violet = default Resource Pack) and put this command into the first `tp @p[score_P1=1,score_P1_min=1] @e[name=P1CP]`
6. In the second command block set this command `tp @p[score_P1=1,score_P1_min=1] ~ ~ ~ ~ 0`
7. In the last set this `scoreboard players set @p[score_carrot=1,score_carrot_min=1] carrot 0`
8. At last, place this command into an another clock-command block to actually let it happen `/execute @p[score_P1=1,score_P1_min=1] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:emerald_block 0 tp @e[name=P1CP] @p[score_P1=1,score_P1_min=1]`

The scoreboard names "carrot" and "P1" and the armor stand name "P1CP" can be changed, but don't forget to change the name in every command block that has the names in it. "minecraft:emerald_block" can be changed into a block of your choice. Make sure your command blocks are in the spawn chunks, so when you can't see the command block's chunks, it will still work.

Comment: The code on your 2nd step is wrong

Comment: It shouldn't. Maybe you are on a wrong version?

Comment: You `/scoreboard objectives add carrot stat.useItem.minecraft.carrot_on_a_stick` for twice

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean with twice?

Comment: Your code 1 and code 2 be same

Comment: Yes I am sorry, this post is a bit old, and your edit got rejected two times, but I approved it. I don't know why I posted the same code twice again. Thanks for taking your time.